# Get Different Random Posts On Every Page Refresh

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I need help displaying different random posts on each page refresh.

I am using the function orderby=rand, but this gives me same random posts on each blog post i have. I need to have different posts on every page refresh, not sure how can i achieve that.

I currently have this code :

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="ltblg text-center">Related Posts</div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => '3','order'=>'ASC','orderby'=>'rand' );
            $recent_posts = new WP_Query($args);
            while( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) :
            $recent_posts->the_post()
        ?>

        <div class="col-md-4 ">
            <div class="blgbox">

                <div class="latebog">
                    <?php
                        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                            the_post_thumbnail();
                        } else {
                               echo "<img src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/bydeaulfblog.png'/>";
                        }

                    ?>
                </div>

                <div class="blogheading blglist relttle">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 15 ); ?>
                    </a> 
                </div>

                <div class="blgdate text-uppercase">
                    <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
                </div>

                <div class="blgtet">
                    <p>
                        <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 25, '...' );?>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="blgrdbtn">Read More
                    <span><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/rightarrw.png" /></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata();
              # reset post data so that other queries/loops work 
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dunno if it makes a difference, but shouldn't it be `RAND()`? Or does WP deal with that?

Comment: @JonStirling Nope. I've just read in codex.wordpress.com to make sure, the exact function is 'orderby'=>'rand'

Comment: if you read further in the codex, it says `Note an "order" parameter needs to be present for "orderby" rand to work.` : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: @Stender You are right. I just added that, but it didn't make any difference..

Comment: do you have a plugin that caches your queries?

Comment: @Stender Nope. I am only using WpEngine Cache system, but just purged the cache and it didn't updated anything.

Comment: WPEngine by default disabled random order for WordPress queries but it can be enabled right via your dashboard.

Comment: @Stender Wasn't familiar with that WPEngine function. Now it is working perfectly. Thank you so much!!

Comment: WPEngine disabled it due to performance - orderby rand, can slow down your site

Comment: but glad to help

Comment: @Stender That's true, but it is something we need, instead of using plugins for that / that will slow down the website as well / Thanks again.